# Type values in lineedit and then add it to a comboBox by clicking a button? PyQt4

Tags: python, button, pyqt, qcombobox, qlineedit

I want to add multiple value typed in lineedit to a combobox by clicking a button (one value at one time). My sample codes are as below:

```
import os, sys

import PyQt4
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        btn = QPushButton()
        le = QLineEdit()
        combo = QComboBox()

        self.grid.addWidget(btn, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(le, 0 , 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(combo, 0, 2)


        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Example()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

If anyone knows how to do it, pls let me know. Appreciated!!

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you made the combo-box editable. Then you wouldn't need the line-edit or button. The user could just type the text in the combo-box editor, and then press enter to add it.

Comment: @ekhumoro would you pls share how to make it edible? Appreciated!!

Comment: You can use [QComboBox.setEditable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#editable-prop). So all you would need to do is add `combo.setEditable(True)` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, the first thing you should analyze is before which event the action is done, in your case when the clicked signal is emitted, so that a slot is connected and in it we manage the logic. To get the text, use the `text()` method of `QLineEdit`, and add it to the `QComboBox` with the `addItem()` method, I added a small logic to validate and can not add non-empty text and also not to repeat the items

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.combo = QComboBox()

        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.le, 0 , 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.combo, 0, 2)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        text = self.le.text()
        # the text is not empty
        if text != "":
            # get items of combobox
            items = [self.combo.itemText(i) for i in range(self.combo.count())] 
            # Add if there is no such item
            if text not in items: 
                self.combo.addItem(text)
```

The variables can only be accessed in the scope of the method that is created so it is not appropriate to make the widget only variables, but attributes of the class since they are accessible in any method of the class. For this we must only put self.

Comment: Thanks you!  Is there any way that I can make the combobox not showing anything(null) on the GUI? Now it just shows the first value I add even if there's multiple values in it... A way I can think of is to use `self.combobox1.addItem("")` to make an empty item.But is there a better way to do so?

Comment: I do not understand you, so you want nothing to be shown, the purpose of QComboBox is to choose an option. As you comment is the only form, it is forced but your requirement is also.

Comment: @ryan9025. You can use `combo.setCurrentIndex(-1)`.